# Appium xpath contain follow not working

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am not able to use xpath contain and follow strategies in Appium. I dont know is it supported in Appium. Api level 19 .
Can anyone please help:
I have to click on Text View showing balance ie. INR .....
So i am using

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@name,'INR')]"));
   and     
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'INR')]"));
```

but nothing works

[image]

Comment: Do you get some kind of Exception or error message in your script? The steps you have shared only attempt to find the element, but don't try to do anything with it.

Comment: @Domestus, yes it's unable to find element..

Comment: you can use driver.findElement(By.accessibilityId("INR 1,567.89"))

Answer (score 6):

@Sahil Sehgal : Becuase your element doesn't have name attribute so you can use text attribute to find element. In the below example I have added check for "Available balance" and "INR". Use the one which suits your need -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Available Balance')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'INR')]")).click();
```

Comment: that is the main issue. I have tried with the above codes but it is not able to find element.

Comment: Can you post error logs? which one did you try? In the solution above, I am using @text not text()

Comment: ,I suppose '@text' is not valid syntax in xpath

Comment: As weird as it seems, @text is correct syntax for xpath when it concerns Appium.

Answer (score 3):

Search with the full text. Hopefully this will work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='INR 1,567.89']")).click();
```

Comment: in the above solution, xpath will work only for this balance (INR 1,567.89 ) when customer balance will change, test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As i see, android.widget.TextView is the class attribute.

Shouldn't your xpath be something like:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'widget')][contains(text(),'INR')]
```

Always try the selector manually in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem you have with your xpath, it is an appium's bug. See this:
[appium issue on emulators](http://discuss.appium.io/t/an-unknown-server-side-error-occurred-while-processing-the/111/4)

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'INR 1,567.89')]")).click();